# PHP pass an object via a function

Tags: php, function, object

I have this function that returns a json object:

```
function getMyFbEvents() {
    global $facebook;
    try {
        $fb_events = $facebook->api('/me/events/');

        foreach ($fb_events["data"] as $fb_event_data) {

            $event_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fb_event_data['id'] . '/?access_token=' . $facebook->getAccessToken()));
            return $event_info;
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $fb_events = null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now if I want to call that object from another page of the script by calling the relative function, how do I do it?

I mean if I want to loop now `$event_info` as if it I was inside that function and get each given data, is there a way?

Maybe it may sound a bit "too much" :)

Comment: Remember that `file_get_contents` will send individual requests to the remote server and you are using it inside a loop, that could make the user wait for a long time (if 10 requests) and it's not a good idea, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of instead of returning from within the loop you need to accumulate all of the values then return

```
function getMyFbEvents() {
    global $facebook;
    try {
        $fb_events = $facebook->api('/me/events/');
        $eventDetails = array();
        foreach ($fb_events["data"] as $fb_event_data) {

            $event_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fb_event_data['id'] . '/?access_token=' . $facebook->getAccessToken()));
            $eventDetails[] = $event_info;
        }
        return $eventDetails;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $fb_events = null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use it just say (make sure you include_once the file that implements getMyFbEvents if it is in a different php file.)

```
$events = getMyFbEvents();
forearch($events as $event){
    echo $event->description;
}
```

On a side note using the `global` keyword is considered bad practice. A cleaner implementation would just pass in the $facebook variable as a parameter to the function

```
function getMyFbEvents($facebook) {
    try {
    //..... the rest of your function
```

Then to call just

```
$var = getMyFbEvents($facebook);
```

Comment: Yes..ok. But this way it won't loop as if I was in the function itself. I need to be able to loop that data like if it was an array

Comment: I think I know what you're after now.